# Using CHtmlView

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

In my MFC application, I display text line by line in CScrollView. Now the new requirement is to display text (and sometimes images) in html format, preserving all effects e.g. bold, italic etc. I know I can use CHtmlView to display html files, but I need to display text stored in memory line by line. Is it possible?

Thanks,
Dmitriy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to simply generate HTML in a memory string and insert it in a CHtmlView.

Our solution (which works pretty well) is to generate a temporary html file (in Windows temp directory) and navigate the CHtml View to this file. In principle:

```
OurTempFileClass theTempFile;
theTempFile.GetStream()->Put(mHTMLString.Get(), mHTMLString.GetLength());

CHtmlCtrl theHtmlCtrl;
theHtmlCtrl.Navigate2(theTempFile->GetFullPath());
```

(this is pseudo code cause we do not use stdlib c++ classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have an existing application, and its view is derived from CScrollView. Is it possible to convert it to use CHtmlView instead? I replaced the base class with CScrollView and have <code>void CBookView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC) { Navigate2("C:\\Shared\\Monte\\mp3Text\\13.html"); }</code> But nothing is displayed.

Comment: I do not exactly get the inheritance relations but I don't think that you should call the Navigate() function in an own OnDraw() function. If you override OnDraw() than everything that should be displayed needs to happen in this function. In this case the CHtmlView::OnDraw Function (which render the HTML content) is never used because you have replaced it with you own OnDraw function.

Comment: But what else should be displayed besides what I myself specify? 
Before migrating to CHtmlView, I always used TextOut() in my own OnDraw(). 
I decided to create a new application based on CHtmlView, if it is too problematic to change my existing application. But I don't know from where to call Navigate2(). In examples that I found it is called from OnInitialUpdate(), but I want to display contents dynamically based on the document I open. Could you please tell me how I can do it?

Comment: Also, here http://www.ms-news.net/f3292/chtmlview-how-to-display-the-html-code-2529385.html somebody claims that he is giving a way to load contents from memory, but I don't see enough information to understand how it is done. Maybe you could give any comments on that? Thank you so much.

Comment: In the link above I can only see the question but nobody claiming that's possible to display from memory. CHtmlView uses the IE to display the HTML content. You do not have full control on the rendering functionality so OnDraw() is definitly the wrong place. Everytime the content you want to display change you need to generate the temporary file and call Navigate2() again. You can do this in any routine you want (even outside of your CHtmlView derived classe).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I moved calling Navigate2() to my Document method, so I expect the html file to be rendered on opening the document. But the view is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I put it to OnInitialUpdate, but without success, too.
void CBookView::OnInitialUpdate() 
{
 CHtmlView::OnInitialUpdate();
 Navigate2("www.google.com");
}

Comment: Never mind. It worked when I got rid of my OnInitialUpdate().

Answer (score 2):

We do something like that for our log.

We just keep a "live" html document and append to it and redisplay it to the html view.

We have implemented a small custom html builder for our own purpose to add items to the html.

You can send a string to an html document with something like :

```
    IHTMLDocument2 *document = GetDocument();
    if (document != NULL) 
    {

        // construct text to be written to browser as SAFEARRAY
        SAFEARRAY *safe_array = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT,0,1);

        VARIANT *variant;
        // string contains the HTML data.
        // convert char* string to OLEstring

        CComBSTR bstrTmp = string;

        SafeArrayAccessData(safe_array,(LPVOID *)&variant);
        variant->vt = VT_BSTR;
        variant->bstrVal = bstrTmp;
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(safe_array);

        // write SAFEARRAY to browser document to append string
        document->write(safe_array);

        //Detach CComBSTR since string will be freed by SafeArrayDestroy
        bstrTmp.Detach();

        //free safe_array
        SafeArrayDestroy(safe_array);

        //release document
        document->Release();
    }
```

Max.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very straightforward

Wait for document loading to be completed by overloading OnDocumentComplete function

```
CHtmlView::OnDocumentComplete( LPCTSTR lpszURL)
{

IHTMLDocument2 *document = GetDocument();

IHTMLElement* pBody = document->get_body();

BSTR str = "your HTML";

pBody-> put_innerHTML(str);

document->close();
document->Release();
}
```

Comment: Does it really answer the question?

Comment: Yes. The requirement was to display in memory HTML using CHtmlView and you can load you HTML in string "BSTR str" for display on CHtmlView